How to link data in Grafana from Elasticsearch to Postgresql

I'm collecting log files and indexing them in Elasticsearch with Apache NIFI
{
  "took" : 340,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 147,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "reis_logs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ntEbcJABF6ckTEoF8CNO",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timestamp" : "2024-07-01 22:03:17.099",
          "logLevel" : "ERROR",
          "pid" : "23404",
          "thread" : "http-nio-8080-exec-17",
          "class" : "c.k.r.c.xauth.UserXAuthTokenController  ",
          "logMessage" : "errors with authenticate [Enable Debug mode for details] : Bad credentials",
          "_raw" : "2024-07-01 22:03:17.099 ERROR 23404 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-17] c.k.r.c.xauth.UserXAuthTokenController   : errors with authenticate [Enable Debug mode for details] : Bad credentials"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "reis_logs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "n9EbcJABF6ckTEoF9CM-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "timestamp" : "2024-07-01 22:03:18.348",
          "logLevel" : "ERROR",
          "pid" : "23404",
          "thread" : "http-nio-8080-exec-13",
          "class" : "c.k.r.c.xauth.UserXAuthTokenController  ",
          "logMessage" : "errors with authenticate [Enable Debug mode for details] : Bad credentials",
          "_raw" : "2024-07-01 22:03:18.348 ERROR 23404 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-13] c.k.r.c.xauth.UserXAuthTokenController   : errors with authenticate [Enable Debug mode for details] : Bad credentials"
        }
      },...

I want in the last table in my dashboard to link the solution for each logMessage from a table in PostgreSQL like the example above (Panel Title)
So I at the end I will have the timestamp (Elastic) + logMessage (Elastic) + the solution text (PostgreSQL)
How can I link the two data or how can I approach this solution?

The solution is to use mixed data type

and use data transformation to join the two data's

